# How to write javascript in kendo grid row template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to write javascript inside kendo grid row template?

Here is my sample code

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <div>
       <dl>
        <dt>
         <label class="iconPlace"><i class="fas fa-plane"></i></label>
         <label class="iconPlace"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>                                     
         <label class="Info"> #:traineeId# (#:traineeName#) </label>
         <label class="rank">#:rank#</label>
        </dt>
       </dl>
    </div>
</script>
```

I want like this

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <div>
       <dl>
        <dt>
         // if(condition) then
         <label class="iconPlace"><i class="fas fa-plane"></i></label>
         // end condition
         <label class="iconPlace"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>                                     
         <label class="Info"> #:traineeId# (#:traineeName#) </label>
         <label class="rank">#:rank#</label>
        </dt>
       </dl>
    </div>
</script>
```

I applied javascript condition start and end with #, but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <div>
       <dl>
        <dt>
         # if (condition) { #
         <label class="iconPlace"><i class="fas fa-plane"></i></label>
         # } #
         <label class="iconPlace"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>                                     
         <label class="Info"> #:traineeId# (#:traineeName#) </label>
         <label class="rank">#:rank#</label>
        </dt>
       </dl>
    </div>
</script>
```